# AVCaptureVideoOrientation not working properly

Tags: ios, swift, avcapturesession

I know this question is all over stack overflow but every answer I use just does not effect the outcome what so ever. My problem is the video orientation is always in landscape left which I've been told is the default videoOrientation. I want it to be in whatever orientation the user is holding the iPhone in (mostly portrait) and here is the code I am using to do that:

```
        previewLayer = AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer(session: captureSession)
        self.cameraView.layer.addSublayer(previewLayer!)

        // Tell the preview layer the orientation to display
        self.previewLayer?.frame = self.view.bounds

        if let connection =  self.previewLayer?.connection  {
            let currentDevice: UIDevice = UIDevice.currentDevice()
            let orientation: UIDeviceOrientation = currentDevice.orientation

            let previewLayerConnection : AVCaptureConnection = connection

            if (previewLayerConnection.supportsVideoOrientation)
            {
                switch (orientation)
                {
                case .Portrait:
                    previewLayerConnection.videoOrientation = AVCaptureVideoOrientation.Portrait
                    break
                case .LandscapeRight:
                    previewLayerConnection.videoOrientation = AVCaptureVideoOrientation.LandscapeLeft
                    break
                case .LandscapeLeft:
                    previewLayerConnection.videoOrientation = AVCaptureVideoOrientation.LandscapeRight
                    break
                case .PortraitUpsideDown:
                    previewLayerConnection.videoOrientation = AVCaptureVideoOrientation.PortraitUpsideDown
                    break


                default:
                    previewLayerConnection.videoOrientation = AVCaptureVideoOrientation.Portrait
                    break
                }
            }
        }

        captureSession.startRunning()
    }
```

For some reason this does not work I still end up getting everything in landscape left. I think the problem lies in the previewLayer, I feel like I was supposed to assign it to something other than:

```
previewLayer = AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer(session: captureSession)
```

Because otherwise it should work but I don't know what to do please help me out I've been on this for hours and hours!

Comment: Did you manage to figure it out? I have the same problem!

Comment: No I have no idea! You could place a bounty on this question if you wish

Comment: Actually I figured out that I was setting my `videoOrientation` to landscape somewhere else in my code. I would suggest in your captureOutput delegate method to print out the videoOrientation to see what orientation it's at.

Comment: alright will do thanks for the help